# Working with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, css, html, contenteditable, caret

Okay, so I am able to edit the content of my DIV just fine. However, there are a couple things I'm trying to work around.

In my editable div, I have a div containing a site address (such as twitter.com), I don't want that to be deletable from the editable DIV; the reason it's in there is so a user could copy all of the text including the domain.

If you remove all of the text except the domain, then the caret doesn't show up - or it does for a second all the way at the right side of the DIV.

And if a user deletes the domain name, it reappears but the caret is now to the left of it which I also don't want.

Any solutions on making the caret always visible and keeping it to the right of the domain?

Oh, and for some reason I can't use onKeyDown on the editable DIV to activate the anylyeText function (at least not in JSfiddle) so I had to do a setTimeout loop.

Here is my fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qycw2/)

CSS:

```
.url {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid rgb(140,140,140);
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(35,155,215);
    cursor: text;
    outline: none;
}
.url:focus {
    border-color: rgb(35,155,215);
}

.noedit {
    display: inline;
    color: rgb(140,140,140);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="url" contenteditable="true" id="textbox"><div class="noedit" contenteditable="false">http://twitter.com/</div>username</div>
```

JS:

```
var analyzeText = function() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
    var textVal = textbox.innerHTML;
    var urlString = '<div class="noedit" contenteditable="false">http://twitter.com/</div>';

    if (textVal.length < urlString.length) {
        textbox.innerHTML = urlString;
        textbox.focus();
    }
    setTimeout(function() { analyzeText(); }, 100);
};

(function(){analyzeText();})();
```

Comment: How about adding a span for the content to be edited and make that span as editable? <div class="url" id="textbox"><div class="noedit" contenteditable="false">http://twitter.com/</div><span contenteditable="true" >username</span></div>

Comment: why a span? The same issues occur if I make the editable div inline-block.

Comment: @SaravananS oh, that doesn't work as I am no longer able to copy the domain & username at the same time.

Comment: Yes. This will not satisfy your 1st usecase then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method using Selection and Range.

[MDN Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection)
[MDN Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)

(If you check out MDN, you'll notice that IE9 support isn't there - prior to IE9, you had to use proprietary IE script. Google can help you out there!)

First thing I do is add these two variables:

```
var range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();
```

Then, I modified your script like so:

```
if (textVal.length < urlString.length) {
    textbox.innerHTML = urlString;

    // We create a text node and append to the textbox to select it
    textbox.appendChild(document.createTextNode(''));

    // Text node is selected
    range.setStart(textbox.childNodes[1], 0);

    // Collapse our range to single point (we're not selecting a word, after all!)
    range.collapse(true);

    // Let's clear any selections
    sel.removeAllRanges();

    // Alright, time to position our cursor caret!
    sel.addRange(range);

    textbox.focus();
}
```

And that's it! Here's an updated Fiddle to demonstrate:

Edit - Updated to include logic to prevent user from inserting text to the left of the domain

http://jsfiddle.net/Qycw2/6/

Comment: Hmm, this code seems a little buggy... sometimes it puts the caret on a new line when the domain reappears. Also, if the user simply clicks to the left of the domain then they can type there (obviously that's a simpler fix than the new line bug)

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Haha at the IE comment. The new line bug I didn't see - what browser are you using to test? (I'm on Mac - tested with Chrome and FireFox)

Comment: If you delete the domain again after it reappears is when a new line is created

Comment: It seems to be just a Safari issue

Comment: Ah, I see. It looks like if you insert an empty text node, Safari decides to throw in a few `br` tags for giggles (or, so the inspector shows...) I updated to include a textNode that isn't empty, and Safari acts better.

Comment: Ah, well.. you have solved all of the issues. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hmmm... apparently this still isn't working fully. when I finish deleting the username the caret still goes all the way to the right for a second. I've tried calling the force function when the user is pressing the delete key.

Comment: Ok, after a few modifications to your code I think I'm liking the results. I doubt there would be any other answers that are less complicated, so I'll accept yours.

Comment: Blast, okay.. I've come up with an Issue I cannot resolve. if the tabs to select the editable div I have done an onfocus event, but if the have already typed a username the caret is going in between the domain and the username instead of at the end of the text. How can I make it go to the end of the text?

Comment: Really enjoyed reading your chat. Working with native `contenteditable` you'll need to chat more ;)